# Return Value From ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: vb.net

I want to return a value from `ExecuteNonQuery`.

My code:

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim comA As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SETTING_TB(SETTING_CODE,SETTING_NAMELOG) VALUES (@SETTING_CODE,@SETTING_NAMELOG)", con)

comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SETTING_CODE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = EMPLOYEEUPDATE_F.LAB_CODEVAL.Text
comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SETTING_NAMELOG", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = EMPLOYEEUPDATE_F.TEXT_NAME.Text

con.Open()
comA.ExecuteNonQuery()
X = comA.ExecuteNonQuery
con.Close()

MsgBox(X)
```

Error message:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

If I delete this part of the code, it works without a problem, how can I return the value?

```
X = comA.ExecuteNonQuery
MsgBox(X)
```

Comment: You have two OleDbCommand. One is named _ComA_ and one _com_ For the second one we don't know what kind of sql is executing. And the error seems to be from the execution of the second command.. Is this second command executing just a typo?

Comment: You typed quickly but there is one practical one query.

Comment: Still two executions. The first one succeeded, the second one fails because it inserts again the same data and this clearly is not accepted by the definition of your table. So just remove the first one and execute only one time the command getting the return value

Comment: You're calling comA.ExecuteNonQuery twice.  Remove the first one and I think it should work as expected.  Also a little off topic but suspect you've mixed the syntax of parameter.AddWithValue() and parameter.Add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
comA.ExecuteNonQuery() 'This line executes the command but ignores the result.
X = comA.ExecuteNonQuery 'This line executes the command again, so will insert duplicate values, and does get the result.
```

It's the first of those two lines you should have deleted, not the second. If you want to insert one record then execute the `INSERT` statement once. If you want to display the result then keep the code that actually gets the result. Delete the execution that doesn't do what you specifically state that you want to do, i.e. get the result.

You could afford to clean up your code in other areas too:

```vb
Dim recordCount As Integer 'Descriptive variable name.

'Use Using statements to create short-lived disposable objects.
'Create your connection object where you use it
Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SETTING_TB(SETTING_CODE, SETTING_NAMELOG) VALUES (@SETTING_CODE, @SETTING_NAMELOG)", connection)
    With command.Parameters
        'Use Add to add parameters.
        .Add("@SETTING_CODE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = EMPLOYEEUPDATE_F.LAB_CODEVAL.Text
        .Add("@SETTING_NAMELOG", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = EMPLOYEEUPDATE_F.TEXT_NAME.Text
    End With

    connection.Open()

    'Execute command once and retain result.
    recordCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using 'Connection closed implicitly when disposed.

'Prefer to not use VB Runtime functions like MsgBox.
MessageBox.Show(recordCount)
```